# Changing Timer on Tor Node Change

Tags: configuration, exit-relays

Tor is changing my node every 10 minutes. With Google I have come across a 'torrc' file that seems to have custom Tor commands, but I'm not sure how to change it so that my node were to change say every 30 minutes, or every 3 hours, or every day, or never.

How is this possible? Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a link to this torrc or paste the relevant content here?

Comment: http://malwaretips.com/threads/how-to-change-ip-address-on-tor-browser-into-specific-country.27653/ It's the file mentioned here, not sure if this is the only way, I'd be happy to do it any other way you know how.

Answer (score 1):

This, like most other things are documented in the [manual](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en).

> **MaxCircuitDirtiness *NUM***
>
> Feel free to reuse a circuit that was first used at most NUM seconds ago, but never attach a new stream to a circuit that is too old. For hidden services, this applies to the last time a circuit was used, not the first. (Default: 10 minutes)

This is probably not that great of an idea, and "TrackHostExits" should probably be used instead, but see the warning in the "TrackHostExits" documentation (the same problem applies with modifying "MaxCircuitDirtiness" upwards).